# How to replace the adopted SD card without reformatting the entire phone?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage, adoptable-storage

I currently have a Fairphone 4 and a 1 TB SD card. It was set up as shared internal storage. Over the past few weeks, I've been having random crashes on the phone which I think may be down to the SD card.

I've got a replacement SD. However, if I use the new SD card, I cannot access any storage on the phone at all. If I insert the new SD card and format it as internal storage, I can see a total storage of 1.19 TB in the Settings app. However, if I go to the files app, I can't browse any folders. With the FX File Manager, it just says access denied whenever I try to navigate into the `/storage` folder.

I can't install any apps/updates on the phone unless I put the old SD card back in. It does exactly the same thing if I take the SD card out entirely, unable to browse the local folders/update any apps.

I'm hoping there's a way to allow access to the new storage area without resetting the entire phone?

Comment: My rule number one when buying a new sd-card is first to test it using a PC a nd a tool like "FakeFlashTest" or "h2testw" just to make sure the sd-card capacity is not faked.

Comment: @Robert Hi thank's for the reply. The SD is a genuine card. It works in other devices (PC etc.). I think the issue is that I'm either missing a step somewhere when setting the new card up that would give the system access to it or there's a bug/flaw in android that requires the phone to be formatted before it'll accept the new card. I say that as it appears that the main storage area is on the old SD card and taking that card out leaves me with no accessible storage on the phone, either with the new SD or without an SD inserted.